# Remove duplicates from String

Tags: java, string

Here is my code,

```
   public static String set_x_dates()
   {
    int noRecords = GlobalData.getNoRecords();
    int n;
    String date = "";
    if (noRecords <= 10)
        for (n = 0; n < noRecords; n++)
            date += Dates[n] + "-" + Month[n] + "|";
    else {
        for (n = 0; n < noRecords; n++) {
            int gap = (int) (noRecords / 10);
            date += Dates[n] + "-" + Month[n] + "|";
            n++;
            if (n != noRecords)
                for (; gap > 0; gap--)
                    date += "|";
        }

    }
    return date;
}
```

I want **to remove duplicate entries** from the string "date" which is being return. Dates[] and Month[] are static int arrays. Can anybody help me?

The output I'm getting is this:

```
25-5|28-5|4-6|8-6|10-6|14-6|17-6|7-7|7-7|7-7|7-7|7-7|7-7|7-7|7-7|7-7|7-7|26-7|26-7|
```

and I want this:

```
25-5|28-5|4-6|8-6|10-6|14-6|17-6|7-7|26-7|
```

Comment: can you post the kind of thing you're getting and what you would like it to be please?

Comment: The output i am getting is                                          25-5|28-5|4-6|8-6|10-6|14-6|17-6|7-7|7-7|7-7|7-7|7-7|7-7|7-7|7-7|7-7|7-7|26-7|26-7|                                                  and I want it as                                                     25-5|28-5|4-6|8-6|10-6|14-6|17-6|7-7|26-7|

Comment: In addition to the suggestion of using a Set I think you may also pass in the noRecords as an argument to set_x_dates, reconsider the name of set_x_dates, and factor out the duplicate lines in your code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of concatenating dates to a string, add your dates to a [`Set`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) as you loop over the records. Sets cannot contain duplicates.

Then at the end of the method, loop over your set and construct a string to return.

Comment: if I do so, I need to change each and every function, as currently they are taking date as String. Below I am providing the code which access the set_x_dates() function.                                                                                  String mUrl += "&chs=" + width + "x326"
    + "&chdl=Systolic|Diastolic|Pulse%20Rate|Average|Target"
    + "&chco=FF9900,66CC00,B34FBF,B6B6B6,00CCFF" + "&chdlp=b"
    + "&chxt=x,y" + "&chls=2|2|2"
    + "&chxl=0:|"
    + set_x_dates()
    + "1:"
    + set_y_values() 
    + "&chd=t:"
    + set_x_grids()
    + "|"
    + set_systolic_p()
    + "|"

Comment: no, you don't. As I said in my answer, at the end of your method, convert the Set back into a string and return it, so you won't have to change any other calling methods.

Answer (score 1):

You could assemble a [Set](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) of strings that will be concatenated after the set is populated.

**Edit:** ah, dogbane got there first :P

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code for removing duplicates in String.

[image]

Output :

[image]